# Click event not firing. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

Using jQuery, I have attached a "click" event handler to some "li" HTML elements.

The problem is: when I click the "li" element, the event does not fire.

"How?" - will you ask... so, see it by yourself [in this simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSPWx/)

Consider:

- I have tested on Firefox 14.0.1 and Chrome 16.0.912.77 in my Ubuntu system.
- I have stripped a lot of stuff from CSS, HTML and JS of my original code while "hunting" the cause.
- You can click in the form **label** elements to see the event handler function working. But try to click in the **li** elements... does not work!
- If you just remove the `float: left` style from the "li" element, or the `position: relative` style from the "form", then the problem disappears!

So, I am not exactly asking how to circumvent or workaround the problem, I am asking **why** the "click" event does not fire. Is this a bug? A bug from what? Browser? jQuery? CSS? It simply does not make sense to me, and I will love to see an explanation!

Thanks.

Comment: i didnt change anything in your code and it works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `li`'s do float and the form has a `position:relative`, the form lies above the `li`'s, therefore you can still click "Image"

BTW.:
If you are using Firebug or Webdeveloper tools you can detect that.

Comment: Indeed... if I just add `z-index: -1` style to the form, I can click in the upper `li`'s. The question really is a CSS one: why `position: relative` makes the `form` stand above the `ul`???

Comment: The problem is not the position relative, but the float, because of that the ul has no width.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your DOM with firebug or something similar you will notice your form is floating over the first elements of your ul, therfore it works on "image" because it is not hidden by your form.
Try to empty your css code in jsFiddle and everything will be working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why click function is not working is
**li** element are not placed inside **form**

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle for you please have a look at it[click action working fine on all elements](http://jsfiddle.net/cSPWx/19/)